# Omniauth and Web2py

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, web2py

I have a complex application built with web2py but I would love to use the power of omniauth to connect with Gmail, Google Apps, twitter, etc.. Does anybody know a way to handle authentication with Omniauth on Rails and then handle the session to web2py?

Comment: Have you considered using Janrain Engage? There's built-in support in web2py for it. http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09#Integration-with-OpenID,-Facebook,-etc.

Comment: Well, I don't like much having to rely on a third party service for that. Otherwise, do you know if Google Apps integration is well supported with Janrain?

Comment: Understandable. Here is their full list of providers. https://rpxnow.com/docs/providers . I have used them with Google auth before and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Janrain is a possibility we'll consider seriously.

Comment: Unfortunately we need to get access to contacts and as I can see in the providers list, this is only available for 'Enterprise' and 'Pro' editions with Janrain.